# Javascript - Sorts a list of objects based on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of the following objects:

```js
[{name : "Mariah" , quantity: 2},
{name : "Vincent" , quantity: 1},
{name :"Albert" , quantity: 1},
{name : "Patrick" , quantity: 1},
{name : "Vincent" , quantity: 2}]
```

I would like to sort this list based first on the quantity field and then alphabetically based on the name field
Something like that

```js
    [{name :"Albert" , quantity: 1},
    {name : "Patrick" , quantity: 1},
    {name : "Vincent" , quantity: 1},
    {name : "Mariah" , quantity: 2},
    {name : "Vincent" , quantity: 2}]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let list = [{name : "Mariah" , quantity: 2},
            {name : "Vincent" , quantity: 1},
            {name :"Albert" , quantity: 1},
            {name : "Patrick" , quantity: 1},
            {name : "Vincent" , quantity: 2}
           ]

let sort = list.sort(function(a,b){
  if (a.quantity != b.quantity){
    return a.quantity - b.quantity
  }else{
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
  }
})

console.log(sort)
```